# Firebase realtime database : Does the user download the entire database every time?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I want the user to send some data to the database. But the downloaded data is a little high.
These are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

In one day, the downloaded data has become 7.2 mb. The size of my database is around 320kb. This is my code where I'm using it.

```
String id = mDatabase.child(username).push().getKey();
Record r = new Record(calendar.getTimeInMillis(),sensorValue);
mDatabase.child(username).child(id).setValue(r);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Unable to understand.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's impossible to say what data your code will read from the database. That said: keep in mind that any data shown in the Firebase console, also counts towards your quota. So refreshing the console 20 times in a day, would also explain your data usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Firebase doesn't download all the data any time you start your application if you don't need it (depends on the data you are querying).

So the correct answer is that it depends on the code of your app. For example if you have code like

```
db.ref('users/user_id').once((snap) => { ... })
```

it means that only particular data, placed under `user_id` field is downloaded.

But if, for example, you write such code:

```
db.ref('users').once((snap) => { ... })
```

the whole `users` object will be downloaded.

Hope, now it is clear for you that bandwidth depends on how much data is queried from your app code perspective.

Answer (score 2):

A common source of unexpected bandwidth usage in the Firebase Realtime Database (and in Cloud Firestore, Firebase's other database), is the fact that any data shown in the Firebase console also counts towards your quota.

So in your case, if you've kept the database open in the Firebase console, and refreshed it 10 times over the day, or if you've opened the Firebase Database console 10 times in a day, you're already well on your way to explaining the bandwidth usage that you have.